# Convert a Delphi example using TDatabase and local paradox table to server storage

Tags: delphi, quantumgrid

I am looking at the Developer Express Quantum Grid example 'IssueList' which is a useful bug reporting and tracking application that's almost ready to go out of the box. It uses a TDatabase component with several paradox (.db) tables.

Is it simple to rejig the TDatabase settings to use a database on a shared machine so that several of us can access it together across the network? If so, what would be the steps needed please?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this... does the fact that it is using Paradox tables mean that it is using the BDE?

Answer (score 1):

This [TI](http://www.adug.org.au/reference/ti3160.htm) describes the settings involved for sharing Paradox databases on a network.

In your configuration you need to set the `working directory` and `private directory` correctly.
Often it is easier not to use aliases for this, but perform all the settings in your `TDatabase.Parameters` property and your TSession.

The working directory must be the same path (sharename, drive letter) for all users.

The private directory must be different for all users.

Here are two links that explain some of the defails you need in more detail:

- [Building one and two tiered apps](http://www.podgoretsky.pri.ee/ftp/Docs/Delphi/D5/dg/one2tier.html)
- [Managing Database Sessions](http://www.podgoretsky.pri.ee/ftp/Docs/Delphi/D5/dg/4_sess.html)

--jeroen

Comment: @Jeroen: +1 for some nice links. I should have made it clear too that I'm not a fan of Paradox and would be very happy to use any other database technology (SQL?) that made this migration easier.

Comment: @Brian: In that case, you could for instance use embedded FireBird for standalone, and FireBird server for shared use?